# Pandas - Column tolist() multiple filter

Tags: python, pandas

How to apply multiple filter to convert column to list

```
data = {'file_type':['excel', 'csv', 'xls', 'csv'],
        'file_name':['my_files.xls', 'txt_file.csv', 'test_file.xls', 'new_file.csv'],
        'oter_col':['other_value1', 'other_value2', 'other_value3', 'other_value4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

my DF

```
  file_type      file_name      oter_col
0     excel   my_files.xls  other_value1
1       csv   txt_file.csv  other_value2
2       xls  test_file.xls  other_value3
3       csv   new_file.csv  other_value4
```

I want to get all excel and xls file type in a single list.

I tried something like

`excel_list = df[df['file_type']=='xls']['file_name'].tolist()`

but I am able to filter only one type when I add additional condition "in, or, and" it fails.

is there an easy way to achieve this without using for loop ?

expected result **['my_files.xls', 'test_file.xls']**

Comment: Try this `excel_list = df[df['file_name'].str.lower().str.endswith(".xls")]` and `excel_list["file_name"].tolist()`

Comment: got solution from [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

answer is :
`excel_list = df.loc[(df['file_type'] == 'xls') | (df['file_type'] == 'excel'), 'file_name'].tolist()`

Comment: Congratulations!!